# What separates a "normal" person from a morally excellent person?

Tags: ethics, kant, aristotle, metaethics, virtue-ethics

Is it simply doing all the duties that Deontology (Kant) requires of you while doing them out of a sense of duty, or having all the virtues suggested by Aristotle while enjoying doing them or even Christian theology..

I'm just wondering if any of these system or philosophers specified when a person is morally good/excellent.

"Do not take what I say as if I were merely playing, for you see the subject of our discussion -- and on what subject should even a man of slight intelligence be more serious? -- namely, what kind of life should one live..." -- Socrates

Answer (score 0):

"*Once a man knows good from evil, nothing on earth can compel him to act against that knowledge*.
    -- Socrates

Assuming Socrates was right, the Moral Excellence is attained when the person achieves Full Rationality,¹ which means having a *system of beliefs* that

1. Is reasonably comprehensive (its coverage) and deep (its resolution).
2. The person themselves can *explain **why*** their beliefs are true, and
3. The explanation of a belief is only valid if
   a) it is rooted in the notion of the objective reality as its first premise, and
   b) is the kind that your grandma would understand (as Albert Einstein would put it)

***¹** Yes, the Gödel incompleteness theorems. The first premise of a fully rational system, the existence of objective reality, is the Kierkegaard's "leap of faith". It has to be assumed (as we knew from a long, long time ago):

  ❝The ignorant think that Spirit lies within knowledge, the wise man knows it beyond knowledge.

      -- Kena-Upanishad*