# Can "why-is" close the "is-ought" gap?

Tags: ethics, epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, hume, rationality

[UPDATE: Clarified that choosing what-ought-to-be from what-can-be is based on our knowledge of *ourselves*, not on our knowledge of good and evil]

“*I know you won't believe me, but the highest form of Human Excellence is **to question** oneself and others*.

“*For you see what our discussions are all about – and is there anything about which a man of even small intelligence would be more serious than this -- **what is** the way we **ought** to live*?

-- Socrates

[The infamous **IS**-**OUGHT** gap](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hume-moral/#io) -- how do we go from the way something **IS** to the way [we think] it **OUGHT** to be? David Hume, like many others before and after him, would see a gap in there, leading them to question our ethics, our science, our ability to choose consciously, and the very existence of the consciousness itself -- thus pitching themselves head-on against, say, Socrates, who was adamant about our [capacity to know good from evil](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/74206/47003).

I suggest that, indeed, what is often perceived as a gap, as void, is, in fact, the very quality that makes us human.

Comment: From https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "Please note that this site is not a personal blog or a pulpit for you to express your own personal philosophical beliefs." This question seems to do just that. A way to appear more compliant would be to ask a succinct question (no longer than 5 sentences) about the is-ought gap, and then put the rest of the text as a self-answer. That could still go against the above warning, but technically it might pass.

Comment: Hume did not see the gap "like many others",  the peculiarity is that all others before him *missed* it, so ingrained the cliche was. And explaining how "it could have been otherwise" does not require any special ability. "Can" is just a part of "is" (with relaxed background assumptions) and gets one no closer to "ought" than why-is gets one to why-should, not to mention that our emotional traits can not resolve logical problems in principle. But your rhetoric shows just how pervasive the gap is, even those aiming at it miss it by falling into sentimental cliches.

Comment: @Conifold -- sorry, i pasted a wrong quote.. The difference between "can" and "ought" is this: "*Know thyself*. -- Socrates

Comment: @Conifold > "*the peculiarity is that all others before him missed [the is-ought gap]*" -- that "peculiarity" is having/being your *conscious, rational Self* (a.k.a. *human soul*). Which, yes, has been a dying art since that moment, a very long time ago, when we began crippling our children in nuclear families.

Comment: @Conifold -- I updated the question, thanks for bringing my attention to it.

Comment: You link to your personal blog in several places in this article (is there even any pretense left that it is a question?). So 1. you already have a place to blog your ideas, and 2. you try to use Stackexchange to self-promote your blog.

Comment: @tkruse -- what would be a better way, save for copying & pasting the article content?

Comment: @tkruse -- My question was whether the is-ought gap is an illusion, caused by some specific kind of cognitive deficiency. Each of the two linked articles describes an epic failure at connecting the dots, also implying the existence of a serious and widespread cognitive deficiency. In legal speak, they call it "establishing a pattern of behavior". And if you are wondering, yes, I do have a model that explains these and many other similar observations -- [Irrationality: The beautiful mind](http://bit.ly/2v1sX8b). That's why the relevance.

Comment: Thank you for writing this. I'm reminded:
The upanishads often end with the mystic mantra "ya evam veda, iti upanishad!" V hard to translate... Roughly: "He who knows this — Oho! The Great Secret!!" This becomes slightly clearer if the _philosophy_  — by a rishi — is embedded in the  _mythology_ where rishis are elusive mysterious humans with unlimited power (eg The Ramayana starts with how God (Vishnu) is compelled to incarnate and suffer as human Ram because of the curse of Narada — a rishi).

Comment: In effect the rishi is one who has bridged the *is* and *ought* by combining knowledge with devotion.  Slightly expanded [ya evam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra_pushpam).
Here [philosophicalized](https://adhyatmawritings.com/2015/03/23/mantra-pushpam-the-hidden-meaning/)

Comment: Staying within the western tradition @Gordon had commented a month or two ago about a French philosopher (early twentieth century, I forget the name) who taught that philosophy in Socratic times  was more a question of lived spiritual discipline, the current deterioration into intellectual gymnastics being not essentially western or christian but a post cartesian artifact.

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up "*...where rishis are elusive mysterious humans with unlimited power*" -- And I think I know *exactly* who they -- the rishis -- were. They weren't that mysterious, but they would look almost alien to us, shattering our core beliefs about humanity and human nature.

Comment: They were fully rational (a sagehood by today’s standards). Mentally healthy -- free of childhood trauma, depression, anxiety, and the rest in the bouquet of mental disorders known as the "human condition". The would share a deep understanding of themselves, their lives, and the world they lived in. Knowing right from wrong they will be, evil-free.² Their beliefs would reflect their shared knowledge of the objective reality, thus keeping them in agreement practically all the time -- no room for *conflicts*, no use for *power hierarchy*, not even power *as the concept*....

Comment: No *competition* for the top spot either. The concept of trust wouldn't be applicable. And none of that would be possible if not for the free love. No slut-shaming, no concept of "slut", and [cooperative breeding](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/evan.20222) as the [cornerstone of their lives](http://bit.ly/2Nk9wgO). Their burials strongly suggest maternal kinship, but it wasn't matriarchy. They simply wouldn't know who their father was! A tribe wasn't a band or mobile village, it was a family. It was Eden, lost when things went horribly wrong at the end of the Bronze Age.....

Comment: As for *rishi* being elusive, at the peak of the Bronze Age, they were anything but. Whole civilizations were by them, including [the Indus Valley Civilization](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/74158/how-likely-is-it-you-are-actually-a-philosophical-zombie#comment207870_74158), the largest, (bigger than Egypt and Sumer combined) and probably the most technologically advanced of its era (tho instead of pyramids they were building amazing cities for the living).

Comment: Is this any deeper than saying that "understanding the problem is the first step to the solution"? Obviously it's not the only step, as you seem to  think it is.... Understanding why something is the way it is doesn't always give you a way to make it the way you want it to be, which in your Platonist-absolutist view is phrased as "ought".

Comment: @Fizz “* Understanding why something is the way it is doesn't always give you a way to make it the way you want it to be*” — yes, if does.. it lets you understand what futures are possible, and choose the best among them.

Comment: Otherwise... how is your day?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

“*Wisdom begins in wonder*.
  -- Socrates

That quality is in our unique ability to *ask and explain **why***.<sup>1</sup> With it, we can go beyond ***what is*** and explain, through logic and reason, ***why** it is so*,<sup>2</sup> and, by that measure, how it ***could have been*** otherwise,<sup>3</sup> thus, giving us *our options* (what-can-be).

“*To understand is to be free.*
  -- Baruch Spinoza

Knowing "what is necessary", what *is* an option and what *isn't*, gives us *freedom-as-the-agency* to choose among options available. And it is the latter choice that, *depending on our [knowledge of ourselves][1]*, gives us the ***ought*** part -- our opinion on how things *should* be.

Note that the chain above is *rational*,<sup>4</sup> all the way through, from "is" to "ought". *Free from normative statements, it makes "ought" descriptive as well*.

#### But it makes no sense at all!

I know.

‟*The Truth holds always, but humans, <strike>always</strike> time and again, prove unable to ever understand it, both before hearing it and when they have first heard it*.
  -- Heraclitus

The "closing the gap" story above contrasts *two distinct kinds of curiosity* -- one is of a cat, the other only humans *can* have. The cat's curiosity is about **WHAT**-**IS** (and we have plenty of that too). The second kind -- the **WHY**-**IS** curiosity -- is, however, optional. A 4 y.o. can easily ask 100s of why's in a single day -- until she starts [getting cordially invited to can it](https://youtu.be/Tf17rFDjMZw). So that's why.

“*The learning of many things does not teach understanding; otherwise, it would have taught Hesiod and Pythagoras, and again Xenophanes and Hecataeus*.
  -- Heraclitus

Human nature, however, is harder to tame. Very often it means a person would long for ***understanding***, but unable to express it as WHY-IS, would keep falling back to WHAT-IS, looking for new ***experiences*** instead... like catching that travel bug. “Beware the barrenness of a busy life,” however, as Socrates would put it. No matter how many experiences, no matter how amazing, they won't quench that empty feeling in your heart. What's missing is your human soul, [your conscious, rational Self](https://journals.openedition.org/philosant/941). There's hardly a substitute for that, but there is hope.

‟*To find your Self, think for yourself*.<sup>5</sup> -- Socrates, who else.

[image]

<sup>1a</sup> e.g. why we -- the adults -- [permit bullying in schools](https://www.reddit.com/r/psychology/comments/gyvmk0/young_children_believe_intervening_in_antisocial/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), despite being physically stronger than our adversaries and enjoying a numerical advantage over them?.. or [what's up with UBI](https://bit.ly/2Z49uQO)? -- it's been 50 years, what are we waiting for? and why we [accept pieces of paper](https://bit.ly/3cxqEKF) for... yes, lemming fallacy, but still?..

<sup>1b</sup> It has been proposed before that the is-ought gap can be closed with "if", but that begs for the question, obviously.

<sup>2</sup> An explanation is a mental-model (not to be confused with "mental-image", a.k.a. "empirical concept" in kantoneese, a.k.a platonic forms), also scientific theory (also platonic particulars as a caricature of it). A mental-model is a <strike>computer</strike> mental simulation of that particular aspect of the objective reality. We can only *understand* something if we have a mental model for it (nothing like Kant's "understanding", which means *having an idea of something*). Connecting individual models (indicated by  going off) creates a more comprehensive simulation of reality, a.k.a. the map, not the territory. Stitching it is a slow process till collected puzzle pieces reach the critical mass and your whole world lights up as all pieces fall into place, and you realize that “*Happiness is a virtue, not a reward*. -- Baruch Spinoza

<sup>3</sup> No other species on Earth have evolved that capacity. Allowing for knowledge sharing, it proved to be invaluable. Before then, an individual had only its *own* experiences to rely on. With knowledge sharing, experiences by one can be shared with literally everyone else.

***All of us** benefit from lessons learned by **one of us**, from that person's discoveries, insights, and inventions, as if it were our **own** discoveries, our **own** lessons*.

<sup>4</sup> "Rational" means explainable.

<sup>5</sup> ... rather than being cool with your subconsciousness speaking "your thoughts" to you. *Consciousness is **doing** the thinking*.

Answer (score -3):

1. The [is-ought gap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem) is a fallacy, it does not need closing.
2. What ought to be is solved by the categorical imperative
3. Curiosity did not close this fallacy.
4. Curiosity is just one of many traits of [human nature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_nature) and  [the human condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_condition), not the only one nor the most important one.

An example for the is-ought gap is homosexuality. Some ancient philosophers argued that it is a sin against nature to do homosexual acts. They inferred what ought to be (no homosexuality) from what seemingly is (no homosexuality in nature). This is also known as the naturalism fallacy. It's not a gap that's needs closing, humanity does not need to justify why homosexuality is immoral, it can just accept it as moral. Hume merely rightly said that just because there does not seem to be homosexuality in nature, does not mean it's morally wrong. Same for other presumed sins of the middle ages and antiquity.

What ought to be, morally, is sufficiently solved by the categorical imperative, based on our reason and the desire of the individual for personal safety, liberty and profit. It is independent of curiosity and "why is", also independent of the current state of nature. It completely avoids the naturalism fallacy also known as the is-ought gap.

Finally "what makes us human" is not a useful question in philosophy. The closest approximation is known as "human nature" and "the human condition". Opposable thumbs, bipedal walking, natural language, toolmaking, our ability to love, to laugh, to learn, to enjoy art, to plan ahead, to know our mortality, to pursue happiness, to engage in diverse sexual acts, to compete for mating partners using various means, to lie, jealousy, hubris and so on.
None of it is logically be more important in "making us human" than the other.

Comment: The contemporary objection to the CI is that it’s guilty of the same thing - “Reason” is not a universal set of principles but a folk model of the effective psychology of successful people. People can and do reason differently, and so the “is-ought” problem re-emerges at the level of dispute.

Comment: People do reason differently, and some "problems" or idiosyncrasies arise, but those are not the "is-ought" problem. People may use the naturalistic fallacy in their reasoning, thus polluting the CI with the is-ought gap, but this does not happen necessarily, and is entirely avoidable.

Comment: @SofieSelnes "*People can and do reason differently*" -- irrational people fall victims to different kinds of logical/cognitive fallacies. Logic itself is a branch of math, and having one's own makes no more sence than having their personal arithmetics.

Comment: Heh, since you brought up the categorical imperative (by which I assume you mean the Kantian concept) as the solution... and since you also mention homosexuality... Kant actually came up with the opposite conclusion than yours in that regard... https://www.jstor.org/stable/27744817 "Kant repeatedly says that through each of the unnatural
vices, a person degrades herself below the level of animals" (MS
425; L 159, 170). He calls homosexual sex, bestiality, and masturbation "the most disgraceful and the most degrading
[conduct] of which the human being is capable" (L 170)."

Comment: But kant's assertions on this topic are generally not regarded as a result of his framework, but merely an artifact of his time. In philosophy, it's important to distinguish pure ideas from contemporary culture of writers.